# How to make msbuild deploy tasks in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I want to make MSBuild targets to make setup file and to deploy it. Right now I'm using build configurations for that. So I have 'Debug', 'Release', 'Make setup' and 'Deploy setup' configurations. And when I want to make setup I have to switch to 'Make setup' configuration and run build. And if I forget to switch back to 'Debug' and run build I'll have to wait again while it is making a setup file. It doesn't seem like natural way to do this things to me. Besides, to edit my build file I have to unload project.

I've seen much more comfortable way to do this with Ant in Eclipse:

[image]

You just double click target you want and it'll build it. Also you can edit build file without closing anything.

So the question is how to make ant-style builds with visual studio? Is there a plugin or something? I mean both MSBuild and Ant scripts will do, but I want this functionality integrated in VS and work with C# projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use msbuild's /p:Configuration=DeploySetup flags to do this from command line.
To make your life easier, you can create a batch(.bat) file that will do that.